# What would be the equivalent camera performance specification of Earth-imaging satellites, compared to consumer DLSRs?

Tags: artificial-satellite, photography, earth-observation, camera, optical

In order to better understand what Earth imaging cameras are like (as seen in Google Earth) from the point of view of a photographer, I've asked the following.

Consumer-grade cameras like DSLRs, mirrorless cameras, etc. are specified by things like ranges of shutter speed, focal length and f/number, and others.

Using these kinds of standards, how might a similarly-written specification for an Earth-imaging satellite look like, and compare?

If there is a way to qualitatively explain operational similarities and differences as well, that would be helpful to read as well.

Comment: Welcome to *Space*, and nice question!  To others who might complain the question is too broad, please pick a representative Earth satellite and edit it into the question.  Or just leave it as is.

Comment: @Basher I've made some edits to your question so it fits better to the Stack Exchange format. I think it still reflects your question but of course you are welcome to edit further.

Comment: @uhoh: Thanks for improving the question.  I wanted to make sure it had a chance to be answered.

Comment: Landsat 8 supposedly has only 30m resolution for RGB and 15m for panchromatic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_Land_Imager That may not be impressive enough as a spec for comparison, maybe a generic spy satellite should be compared as well.

Comment: You may compare the focal length and the aperture of the lens and the size of the image measured in pixels. But the satellites cameras often use many more wavelength ranges than only three.